# Некоректное отображение верстки письма

Tags: html, вёрстка, email, table

Есть сверстанное на таблицах письмо. Отправлено было при помощи [этого сервиса](http://sendhtmail.ru/) на почту гугл и на почту моего хостинга (roundedCube). В почте гугл письмо пришло битое
[image: скрин почты гугла]

на почту хостинга пришло нормально,

[image: скрин почты хостинга]

но когда я его переслал на гугл
потерялась одна картинка

[image: скрин пересланного сообщения на почту гугл]

Все картинки добавлял при помощи [этого сервиса](http://anosov.me/services-base64image/)

ссылка на код в комментах, если кто то покажет как ее вставить - буду благодарен

Кстати в jsfiddle все норм работает в браузерах тоже, верстка не плывет, проблема значит в том что я криво подключил картинки, но не могу понять где косяк. Подскажите, что не так, как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: картинки у вас на сайте , да ? и они открываются просто вставкой в адресную строку без проблем ?

Comment: нет, на ПК. те картинки которые в письме есть, когда по ним кликаешь открыть в соседней вкладк - они норм открываются.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/51gr9vj2/

Comment: гугл режет такие base64 картинки (и еше много чего режет, и не только гугл), будет работать только с прямым урлом

Comment: если прямую ссылку с сайта - то все работает, но эти картинки (кроме лого) на сайте не используются, заливать их туда чтобы просты были ради рассылки.. а с гуглдиска ссылка на картинку не катит. Я видел рассылку писем у фрилансхант, у них ссылки идут на раздел их сайта, который защищен и не показан пользвателю (сообщение об ошибке появляется). Как мне реализовать это?